# how to reset variable after elements are finished

Tags: jquery

hi every one i maked some code in order to make some custom css according to tr and td classes and this is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#data tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("two");
$("#data tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("one");  
event.preventDefault();
$('.two').each(function(){
var i=1;
$('.two > td').each(function(){
$(this).addClass('d'+i);
i=i+1;
});
});
});
```

and this what i get if i have much more than ONE of class="two"

```
<table id="data">
<tr class="two">
<td class="d1">some text here</td>
<td class="d2">some text here</td>
</tr>
<tr class="one">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="two">
<td class="d3">text here</td>
<td class="d4">text here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and thiss what i would like to get

```
<table id="data">
<tr class="two">
<td class="d1">some text here</td>
<td class="d2">some text here</td>
</tr>
<tr class="one">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="two">
<td class="d1">text here</td>
<td class="d2">text here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$("#data tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("two");
$("#data tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("one");
$('.two td').addClass(function () {
    return 'd-' + (this.cellIndex + 1)
});
```

---

You need to iterate over the `td` of current `tr`

```
$("#data tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("two");
$("#data tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("one");
event.preventDefault();
$('.two').each(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $('td', this).each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('d' + i);
        i = i + 1;
    });
});
```